# SSJS Error - Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I am new to SSJS and trying to create a test DE. But it's failing. I have created the below cloud page to troubleshoot the error.

```
    %%[ 
    VAR @Result
]%%

<script  runat="server">

    Platform.Load("core","1");

    try {
var guid = Platform.Function.GUID();
var name = "Chandan my test de";

var de = {
    Name: name,
    CustomerKey: guid,
    Description: "Another DE added via SSJS",
    Fields: [{
        FieldType: "Text",
        Name: "ID",
        MaxLength: 36,
        IsPrimaryKey: true,
        IsNillable: false,
        IsRequired: true
    },
    {
        FieldType: "Text",
        Name: "Name",
        MaxLength: 200
    }]
}
    var res = prox.createItem("DataExtension", de);
   

    } 
    catch (ex) {
        Write("An error has occurred: " + Stringify(ex));
        Variable.SetValue("@Result", Stringify(ex));  //sets above ampscript variable
    }

</script>
//// some basic page html goes here/////
%%=v(@Result)=%%
```

The error shown is

> An error has occurred: {"message":"Object expected:
> createItem","jintException":"Jint.Native.JsException: Exception of
> type 'Jint.Native.JsException' was thrown.\r\n at
> Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(MethodCall methodCall)\r\n at
> Jint.Expressions.MethodCall.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at
> Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(MemberExpression expression)\r\n at
> Jint.Expressions.MemberExpression.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at
> Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(VariableDeclarationStatement
> statement)\r\n at
> Jint.Expressions.VariableDeclarationStatement.Accept(IJintVisitor
> visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(BlockStatement
> statement)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.BlockStatement.Accept(IJintVisitor
> visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(TryStatement
> statement)","description":"Jint.Native.JsException: Object expected:
> createItem\r\nException of type 'Jint.Native.JsException' was thrown.
>
> - from Jint\r\n\r\n"} //// some basic page html goes here///// {"message":"Object expected:
>   createItem","jintException":"Jint.Native.JsException: Exception of
>   type 'Jint.Native.JsException' was thrown.\r\n at
>   Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(MethodCall methodCall)\r\n at
>   Jint.Expressions.MethodCall.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at
>   Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(MemberExpression expression)\r\n at
>   Jint.Expressions.MemberExpression.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at
>   Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(VariableDeclarationStatement
>   statement)\r\n at
>   Jint.Expressions.VariableDeclarationStatement.Accept(IJintVisitor
>   visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(BlockStatement
>   statement)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.BlockStatement.Accept(IJintVisitor
>   visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(TryStatement
>   statement)","description":"Jint.Native.JsException: Object expected:
>   createItem\r\nException of type 'Jint.Native.JsException' was thrown.
> - from Jint\r\n\r\n"}

Answer (score 1):

I did not included the  // initialize WSProxy function, and once I added it, the issue got resolved. Below is the correct code:

```
 <script type='javascript' runat='server'>
    Platform.Load('core', '1');
    // initialize WSProxy
    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    
    var guid = Platform.Function.GUID();
    var name = "Chandan my test de";
    
    
    var de = {
        Name: name,
        CustomerKey: guid,
        CategoryID: xxxxxx,
        Description: "Another DE added via SSJS",
        Fields: [{
            FieldType: "Text",
            Name: "ID",
            MaxLength:18,
            IsPrimaryKey: true,
            IsRequired: true
        },
        {
            FieldType: "Text",
            Name: "Name",
            MaxLength: 200
        }]
    }
        var res = prox.createItem("DataExtension", de);
    
        </script>
```